# How to CSS my table so that the most right column stuck to the right, with variable width

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a 100% width table of which I want the right most column (D) to take only the minimum required width, but still stuck to the right with the other columns (B, C) fill up the rest of the space. (A is fixed width).

**How can I do this with CSS?**

[image: table example]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup

Comment: @connexo I know the specs. But knowing is *only* half the battle. ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this question being downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
table td:first-child { width: 50px; }
table td:last-child { width: 1px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

This takes advantage of the standard cell behaviour of being *at least as wide as the non-wrappable content*.

Comment: It does not work with `table-layout: fixed` though, but seeing I don't want that behaviour anyway, it's perfect.